# How to change controllers visibility from another WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 WinForm in Form1 i have Panel and i load Form2 inside Panel(in Form1)

- My code for open From2 inside Panel1

  ```
  Form2 f = new Form2();
  f.TopLevel = false;
  panel1.Controls.Add(f);
  f.Show();
  ```
- In Form2 i have button for close the Form and hide the Panel , i can close the Form2 but i can't hide the Panel1
- I don't know how to change the visibility of Panel1 to False

Comment: try `f.Parent.Visible = false;`

Comment: the close Button is in the form2 
i want to use that to change the visibility of panel1 in form1

Comment: I assume that the `panel1` referenced in the code snippet is the same one we're talking about? Then is should be `f.Parent.Parent.Visible = false;` The close button is a child of `Form2`, which is in turn a child of `Panel1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Form.Closed`event on Form2. Here you can add code for hiding the panel.

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.TopLevel = false;
f.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed; //Add this line
panel1.Controls.Add(f);
f.Show();
```

[About the Form.Closed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed(v=vs.110).aspx)